# Bezierpath with rounded corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath

I am using the following code to show the pointer like triangle view as shown in image below.

```
 UIView *triangleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0f,58.0f, self->_createAccountView.frame.size.width ,20.0f)];
    UIBezierPath* trianglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [trianglePath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake((self->_createAccountView.frame.size.width/7) -8, (self->_createAccountView.frame.size.height/4))];
    [trianglePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake((self->_createAccountView.frame.size.width/5) , 0)];
    [trianglePath closePath];
    trianglePath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;

    CAShapeLayer *triangleMaskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [triangleMaskLayer setPath:trianglePath.CGPath];
    triangleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.00 green:1.00 blue:1.00 alpha:1.0];

    triangleView.layer.mask = triangleMaskLayer;
    [self->_AccountView addSubview:triangleView];
```

This works fine but I want the pointing edge of the triangle view to be rounded. How can make it rounded? Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This does not work!

Comment: Set lineCapStyle to kCGLineCapRound (On the bezier path) to draw the ends of the lines with a round edge.

Comment: triangleView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
This makes the corner radius curve but of the left hand side angle of this triangle. other than this nothing is working linecapstyle is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `lineJoin` to `kCALineJoinRound`.

triangleMaskLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;

Comment: "@" Armands do you have any idea about why linejoin and kCGLineCapRound are not working in my case?

Comment: You can always use `- (void)addArcWithCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)radius startAngle:(CGFloat)startAngle endAngle:(CGFloat)endAngle clockwise:(BOOL)clockwise`

Comment: Or try setting `triangleMaskLayer.masksToBounds = YES `. I believe it's required for `lineJoin` to be visible.

Comment: Check from line 344 of: https://github.com/liufengting/FTPopOverMenu/blob/master/FTPopOverMenu/FTPopOverMenu.m